# Is lightning-record-form compatible with Digital Experiences?

Tags: lightning-experience, digital-experience, salesforce-sites

I am returning the 'Unauthorized access' error on a Digital Experience site when using https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-form.

However, the Site Profile has Create and Read access on the object referenced in the object-api-name attribute.

I am not returning anything in the logs (a log isn't even generated, actually for the Site user).

It would seem that the lightning-form component is not compatible with Salesforce Sites / Digital Experiences - is that correct?

Comment: It's compatible with the Digital Experiences. It's hard to suggest anything for now. Please, provide more information, the code, for example.

Comment: I meant to say is it compatible *within* the context of Salesforce Sites. Thanks

Comment: It is compatible, we use it in DE sites for a couple of projects. So maybe an issue with your implementation.

Comment: Does this issue happen only after the form is used to create a new record?